# Versions of the Bellman Equation

Tags: reinforcement-learning, bellman-ford

In my browsing of various material about reinforcement learning, I have found two versions of `V` and `Q` equations:

This pair:

`V(s) = max<sub>a</sub> (sum<sub>s'</sub> P(s'|s,a) (R(s,a,s') + lambda V(s')))`

`Q(s,a) = sum<sub>s'</sub> P(s'|s,a) (R(s,a,s') + lambda max<sub>a'</sub> Q(s',a'))`

And this pair:

`V(s) = R(s,a) + max<sub>a</sub> (sum <sub>s'</sub> P(s'|s,a) lambda V(s'))`

```
Q(s,a) = R(s,a) + sum<sub>s'</sub> (P(s'|s,a) lambda max<sub>a'</sub> Q(s',a'))
```

The main difference is whether `V` and `Q` include an immediate reward in their value, and whether the value of a state is solely determined by a state or by a transition. While I see the later pair less often, I am sure it is correct.

Do these or any other differences between these two impact how various reinforcement algorithms work?

Answer (score 1):

The first pair is used  when the reward is deterministic for a given state and action, the second pair is used when the reward is also stochastic.

Actually, the environment determines which pair you have to use. For example, in environments like Atari-2600, the first pair is valid since for a given state and action you always get same reward value.